# How to create a pagination using prisma, Next.js and shadcn/ui Data Table?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datatable, prisma

I've connected my planetscale db to my next app using prisma and successfully displayed the data in a table by using shadcn/ui Data Table. but in that data table there is a pagination functionality which will automatically paginate the given data with it's size. but to run it clean i need to fetch by using the pagination directly while fetching.

so for that i used zustand for state management and tried to apply the skip and take in prisma for indexing. and that's where i faced the problem.

in my store page `/store` i have a separate component called `StoreTable`

```
"use client";
import { Products, columns } from "@/app/store/columns";
import { DataTable } from "@/app/store/data-table";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { useProductPagination } from "@/lib/store/product-pagination";
import React from "react";

async function getData(): Promise<Products[]> {
  const { page, perPage } = useProductPagination();
  const products = await prismadb.product.findMany({
    skip: perPage,
    take: page,
  });

  return products.map((product, i) => ({
    id: i + 1,
    name: product.name,
    description: product.description,
    category: product.category,
    origin: product.origin,
    sell: product.sellingPrice,
    purchase: product.purchasedPrice,
    amount: Math.random() * 100,
    status: product.status == "active" ? "active" : "inactive",
  }));
}

async function StoreTable() {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <div className="w-screen  pr-4 sm:pr-8 md:pr-10 max-w-7xl mx-auto">
      <DataTable data={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default StoreTable;
```

when i run this it throws an error `useRef only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-client-hook-in-server-component`. the getData function requires a server action while the hook from zustand requires a client side rendering. so is there a better way to handle pagination?

in my data-table i try to do this.

```
<Button
              variant="outline"
              className="h-8 w-8 p-0"
              onClick={() => {
                 setPage(page + 10);
                 setPerPage(perPage + 10);
              }}
              disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}>
              <span className="sr-only">Go to next page</span>
              <FiChevronRight className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
```

and my zustand store is

```
import {create} from 'zustand'

interface ProductPagination {
    page: number
    perPage: number
    setPage: (page: number) => void
    setPerPage: (perPage: number) => void
}

export const useProductPagination = create<ProductPagination>()((set) => ({
    page: 10,
    perPage: 0,
    setPage: (page: number) => set({ page}),
    setPerPage: (perPage: number) => set({ perPage})
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you need to separate your server-side and client-side logic more clearly. Here's a suggestion on how you can achieve pagination in your scenario:

Keep your pagination logic within the client-side code where Zustand is used.
Fetch the data from the server-side when needed based on the pagination parameters set by Zustand.

Generally, when you get that error it means you're trying to use a client-side hook or functionality in a server-side component. You must have used `useRef` somewhere in the code, and not used `use client;` directive at the top of the file